# Using Custom Themes in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, themes

I downloaded UxStyle to patch my system files to get custom themes working. Now I realized that I like the classy look of Windows 7 the best and want to go back to that. That is simple enough. But the question I have is if I uninstll UXstyle will it change the modifications it made to my system files. If not how do I go about and restore my system to its initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UxStyle does not patch any system files like most patchers used to. Instead, UxStyle runs in the background (as a Windows service) and patches the *memory* of the system where the relevant files were loaded instead of the actual files on disk. This has the benefit that Windows updates and restores do not require re-patching.

As such, when you uninstall UxStyle (or simply stop the running program), its effects go away until you reinstall and run the program.

Therefore, since none of the system files were modified, there is nothing to restore.

Comment: Wow. Thats Pretty Cool. Didnt Know that. Thanks for the help!So does that mean after installing a custom theme I stop UXSTyle from running the theme will stop working and the computer will crash and be unable to load back?

Comment: No problem. Actually a lot of programs that modify the system have moved away from the system-file–patching model to a driver/service model because it makes things much easier and generally safer.

Comment: What about the second part of my comment?

Comment: No, it just means that Windows will be unable to load the theme because as far as the built-in theme-parser is concerned, it is not an officially supported theme. At most, it will complain about the theme being “corrupt” or unsupported and load a/the default theme.

Comment: Okay. So I really dont even need to set a system restore point before installing a custom theme right?

Comment: A theme? No, you shouldn’t need to. (Though Windows will/may automatically create a restore point before a program is installed or uninstalled.) Also, before uninstalling UxStyle, you can manually set the theme to a default one if you want extra peace of mind.